# LINQ to SQL Insert from WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a simple table that I want to be able to edit (update and insert new records) with a datagrid in WPF.  I am using LINQ to SQL classes, and it basically works, but I don't really understand if I'm going about it correctly.

When I insert a new row, the data grid automatically assigns 0 to the ID column (it is an autogenerated primary key).  So I added a check to the RowEditEnding handler as such:

```
        private void Submittal_EditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.IsNewItem)
        {
            //We want to add to our observable collection, and then update the database.
            int i = -1; // this will be the new ID value for insert
            Submittal subAdded = (Submittal) e.Row.Item;
            subAdded.SubID = i;
            _dataDc.Submittals.InsertOnSubmit(subAdded);
        }
        _dataDc.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

When I declare subAdded and set it equal to the cast row item, is that a copy of the row item, or am I directly modifying the object created by the Datagrid?  It seems to work, but it occurs to me that would imply that C# is automatically giving me the equivalent of a pointer in c.  I don't know enough about C# to decide if that's true, and my searches have not given me any concrete answers.  Is this behavior from C#, or is it from WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are *directly modifying the object created by the datagrid*. In fact, if you are bound (as you should be), you are actually modifying *the bound item*.

All classes are *reference types*, which is *similar* to a pointer type in other languages. The exceptions are `struct`s and the basic types like `int`, `char`, etc. which are *value types*. You are getting (and casting) a reference, so your changes propagate to any other references pointing to that object

So you have it right, part of the behavior (the bound item) is from WPF, and the rest (reference types) is part of C#.